# How to call super in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I have a `classB` which extends `classA`.

In both `classA` **and** `classB` I define the method `fooBar()`.

In `fooBar()` of `classB` I want to call `fooBar()` of `classA` at the beginning.

Just the way I'm used to, from Objective-C. Is that possible in PHP? And if so, how?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
parent::fooBar();
```

Straight from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php):

> The ... double colon, is a token that allows access to ... overridden properties or methods of a class.
>
> ...
>
> #### Example #3 Calling a parent's method
>
> ```
> <?php
> class MyClass
> {
>     protected function myFunc() {
>         echo "MyClass::myFunc()\n";
>     }
> }
>
> class OtherClass extends MyClass
> {
>     // Override parent's definition
>     public function myFunc()
>     {
>         // But still call the parent function
>         parent::myFunc();
>         echo "OtherClass::myFunc()\n";
>     }
> }
>
> $class = new OtherClass();
> $class->myFunc();
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 91):

Just a quick note because this doesn't come up as easy on Google searches, and this is well documented in php docs [if you can find it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). If you have a subclass that needs to call the superclass's constructor, you can call it with:

```
parent::__construct(); // since PHP5
```

An example would be if the super class has some arguments in it's constructor and it's implementing classes needs to call that:

```
class Foo {

  public function __construct($lol, $cat) {
    // Do stuff specific for Foo
  }

}

class Bar extends Foo {

  public function __construct()(
    parent::__construct("lol", "cat");
    // Do stuff specific for Bar
  }

}
```

You can find a more motivating example [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150318062403/http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/6/10/1).

Comment: link for  motivating example is gone

Comment: @Jonathan I've updated the link to look up the article on Wayback machine