# Calling a super method in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Can you do something like this in PHP:

```
function foo()
{
    super->foo();

    // do something
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what *super* is? Are you inside a class with this?

Comment: @Pekka: super is the keyword Java uses to access its parent class's constructors and methods.  Other languages may also use this keyword.

Comment: @R. Bemrose ah, okay. That also explains why so many people said "parent" right away

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call super in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961907/how-to-call-super-in-php)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Yes, it's called `parent::` though.

```
public function foo()
{
    parent::foo(); // this is not a static method call, even though it looks like one

    //do something
}
```

Comment: I have already +1'd this answer, yet I find myself here again.  So easily I forget these things.

Comment: @Mike, I would +1 that comment if it was possible... :)

Comment: I forget it because it's such a weird syntax. It feels like calling a static method.

Comment: Welcome to PHP!

Comment: Yes that tripped me up it not being a static call

Answer (score 14):

use [parent](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php);

`parent::foo();`

Comment: `->` will trigger fatal error. Always use `::`. PHP will call parent in same mode (instance/static) as child was called.

Comment: yeah, I miswrote that and fixed within 10 seconds ;)

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean calling the parent class method? In that case you would do:

```
class Bar
{
  public function foo()
  {
    // blah
  }
}


class Baz extends Bar
{
  public function foo() 
  {
    parent::foo();
  }
}
```